# Check the existence of a table using SQL when the database name is passed to it

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a stored procedure designed to be run against a number of similar tables.  Since we archive our databases each year, it takes parameters of not only table name but also database name.

The problem is, I want to check that the table exists, but I do not know the database name ahead of time.  Ordinarily I could do this:

```
IF  EXISTS (
SELECT * 
FROM [Database].sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
 AND type in (N'U'))
```

But having the DB name passed to it as a variable means I'm pretty sure sys.objects is going to get kind of ratty with me.

Is this possible?

Comment: You'll need to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamic sql. Notice the space before each new statement to act like new line

```
declare @db varchar(50) = 'mydbname'
declare @TableName varchar(50) = 'mytablename'
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql = 'use '+@db

set @sql = @sql + ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('''+@TableName+''') AND type in (''U''))  
begin 
     select 1 
end'

exec (@sql)
```